# Miklos schweitzer 2019 P4

Tags: combinatorics

> An $n \times m$ matrix is nice if it contains every integer from $1$ to $mn$ exactly once and $1$ is the only entry which is the smallest both in its row and in its column. Prove that the number of $n \times m$ nice matrices is $\frac{(nm)!n!m!}{(n + m − 1)!}$.

This is a question from [Miklos Schweitzer competition 2019](https://www.bolyai.hu/SCHWEITZER/Feladatsor_angol_2019.pdf). Could anyone who has the solution post the answer?

> **This problem was posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/297385/34538) (and solved) in 2018.**

Comment: It is [this file](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwi9lKC3pPTnAhVM2KQKHd53DK0QFjAAegQIBRAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bolyai.hu%2FSCHWEITZER%2FFeladatsor_angol_2019.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1cHNciYSUU6ceahAoiLBXE). Did you ask for solutions there (email)?

Comment: This problem was posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/297385/34538) (and solved) in 2018.